# How to access OAuth2AuthorizedClient in Webflux Functional Endpoints?

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux, project-reactor

With the classic MVC-style RestController it's easy to get the OAuth2AuthorizedClient, all I need to do is this:

```
@GetMapping("/foo")
public Foo getFoo(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient OAuth2AuthorizedClient client){
    return new Foo(client.getPrincipalName());
}
```

With Webflux's functional endpoints, however, how can I access the OAuth2AuthorizedClient in a similar fashion?

EDIT:

To make it more clear, I'm aware that the reactive approach works the same as the non-reactive one. What I'm curious about is how I can access the OAuth2AuthorizedClient from Webflux's functional endpoints:

```
PersonRepository repository = ...
PersonHandler handler = new PersonHandler(repository);

RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route = route()
    .GET("/person/{id}", accept(APPLICATION_JSON), handler::getPerson)
    .GET("/person", accept(APPLICATION_JSON), handler::listPeople)
    .POST("/person", handler::createPerson)
    .build();


public class PersonHandler {

    // ...

    public Mono<ServerResponse> listPeople(ServerRequest request) {
        // ...
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> createPerson(ServerRequest request) {
        // ...
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getPerson(ServerRequest request) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

For example, in the createPerson method, how do I access OAuth2AuthorizedClient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution!

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OAuth2Utils {

    private final ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository;

    public Mono<OAuth2AuthorizedClient> extractOAuth2AuthorizedClient(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.principal()
                .filter(principal -> principal instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken)
                .cast(OAuth2AuthenticationToken.class)
                .flatMap(auth -> authorizedClientRepository.loadAuthorizedClient(auth.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), auth, request.exchange()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it works the same as in non reactive approach.

Please take a look on:

- docs:
  https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/webflux-roac.html
- example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/5.1.0.RELEASE/samples/boot/oauth2webclient-webflux

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm actually aware of that, I was talking about Webflux's functional endpoints. Check this out
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn